# Safari not displaying font correcty but others does why?

Tags: css, font-face, truetype, safari

i have the following css for my website

```
@font-face {
 font-family: 'malayalam';
 src: url("../fonts/mal/kartika.eot"); /* EOT file for IE */
 src: url('../fonts/mal/kartika.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype');
 src:  local('malayalam'), 
    url("../fonts/mal/kartika.ttf")   format('truetype') 
    url("../fonts/mal/kartika.woff") format("woff"),
    url('../fonts/mal/kartika.svg#Kartika') format('svg');
}
```

its working well for IE,FireFox (Waterfox) and Chrome but not on Safari (Win7) 
above font [kartika](http://www.fontpalace.com/font-details/Kartika/) is a unicode font coming with windows

The problem is for a character "ര്‍ " (shows well in all browsers as described above) is shown as "ര്" in  Safari (Win7)

May i know why? is there any soln to this ?

Comment: Kartika is a copyright-protected font, so you should stop trying to use it on web pages (unless you can persuade Microsoft to give you permission to use it).

Comment: @Jukka K. Korpela thanks for the info ! i will change the font ,problem with other fonts are same as this though!

Comment: If you have a general problem with fonts, please post sufficient information that actually demonstrates the problem. This typically consists of HTML and CSS files together with a reference to origin of fonts (where they were originally loaded and how they were converted for web use). Quite often, posting also a live URL saves everyone’s time considerably.

Answer (score 0):

It could be you don't have unicode settings turned on for those browsers, or perhaps the way the text is aligned could be the cause:

> Solution for the blogger: This issue happens when the text is
>   formatted with align="justify" or letter-spacing:..em;. Either remove
>   justfy or change that to something else like left/right/center.

https://sites.google.com/site/cibu/unicode-how-to